# Regular expression find/replace to adjust word found in all lines starting with a given string

Tags: regex

I need to create a regex which can be used in a find/replace function to only affect lines starting with a particular string. In this case all relevant lines start with;

```
### $BLOCK
```

All such lines continue with a series of words separated by commas and spaces. E.g.;

```
### $BLOCK word1, word2, word3
```

The regex needs to be able to find a particular word (e.g. word2) and adjust spelling (e.g. to wordtwo) irrespective of its place in the series.

I.e., another line in the doc might be;

```
### $BLOCK word2, word4, word1
```

Running the regex in a find/replace needs to produce a doc where the example lines above have been changed to;

```
### $BLOCK word1, wordtwo, word3

### $BLOCK wordtwo, word4, word1
```

I'd really appreciate any assistance. I don't know anything about regular expressions but being able to do this would be extremely useful.

David

Comment: Please post your attempts. You can't simply ask for a solution without demonstrating your efforts.

Comment: my apologies—i've adjusted question to make clear that I don't know anything about regex

Comment: Are you using any programming language to achieve it?

Comment: @dtcooper Well, in this case it's better for you to try to learn regex. This way you'll actually be able to solve future problems. Asking for a ready solution doesn't really help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex:

```
^(###\s+\$BLOCK.*?)\bword2\b
```

OR

```
^(### +\$BLOCK.*?)\bword2\b
```

Replacement string:

```
\1wordtwo
```

I asumed that there must be only one word2 present for each line.

Comment: or `^(### \$BLOCK.*?)\bword2\b`

Comment: Wonderful stuff! Works perfectly, really appreciate your help. David